# Jquery Drag Drop Clone Transform Glitching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, transformation

The cloned elements should be transformable, drag-able and restraint to the container box. But now they are jumping all over the place I'm not sure what the problem is, and the controls should only be visble for the active element.

```
$('.trans').freetrans();

$(function(){    
 //Make every clone image unique.  
   var counts = [0];  
   $(".dragImg").draggable({
                         helper: "clone",
                         //Create counter
                         start: function() { counts[0]++; }
                        });

$("#dropHere").droppable({    
       drop: function(e, ui){
               if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dragImg")) {
     $(this).append($(ui.helper).clone());                   
   //Pointing to the dragImg class in dropHere and add new class.
         $("#dropHere .dragImg").addClass("item-"+counts[0]);
            $("#dropHere .img").addClass("imgSize-"+counts[0]);

   //Remove the current class (ui-draggable and dragImg)
         $("#dropHere .item-"+counts[0]).removeClass("dragImg ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging");

$(".item-"+counts[0]).dblclick(function() {
$(this).remove();
});     
    make_draggable($(".item-"+counts[0])); 
        $(".imgSize-"+counts[0]).mousedown(function() {
            $(event.target).freetrans();              
        });
        //this doesn't work...
        //$(".imgSize-"+counts[0]).mousedown(function() {
            //$(event.target).freetrans('controls', false);              
        //});
       }

       }
      });    


var zIndex = 0;
function make_draggable(elements)
{   
    elements.draggable({
        containment:'parent',
        start:function(e,ui){ ui.helper.css('z-index',++zIndex); },
        stop:function(e,ui){
        }
    });
}    



   });
```

js fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/vjeAV/58/

Answer (score 0):

Its throwing an exception behind the scenes..jQuery UI 1.8.18. isn't selected, and it should also be `onLoad`

> Object [object Object] has no method 'draggable'

I also updated your code.  I removed your bind, and added it to `dragstop`:

```
$('.draggable').on('dragstop',  function (event, ui) {
  var $temp = $(ui.helper).clone().draggable()
  $(this).after($temp ); 
  $temp.freetrans('controls', true);
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vjeAV/)

Comment: Thanks! unfortunately it appears even with that it not working as expected. I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Are you talking about the glitchyness?  You didn't update the fiddle to use the above code.

Comment: I was unsuccessful at making your code work for me; maybe I was doing something wrong? But it was still very glitchy do you know why?